# Números Múltiplos e Primos JAVA

Tags: java

Escrever um código Java para imprimir de 1 a 100 em ordem crescente, informando se o número é par, ímpar, múltiplo de 3, de 4 ou de 5. Se o número for 
múltiplo de 5, escreva outro "for" dentro do "if" para, imprimir todos os números múltiplos de 5 antes dele em ordem decrescente. E no final verifique se os números 
são primos.
Meu código está assim:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int x = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Número par : " + i);
            for (int j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Múltiplo de : " + j);
                    if (i % x == 0) {
                        for (int k = i; k ==0; k--) {
                            System.out.println(" Multiplos de 5 : " + k);
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Número ímpar: " + i);
            for (int j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Múltiplo de : " + j);
                    if (i % x == 0) {
                        for (int k = i; k == 0; k--) {
                            System.out.println("Multiplos de 5: " + k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Ok, e qual é a sua dúvida? Onde está dando erro? O que você não entendeu?

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo achar os múltiplos e coloca-los em ordem decrescente, e o erro com os Primos é que eu não consigo achar eles.

Answer (score 1):

Dá para simplificar a sua lógica, levando em conta algumas coisas:

- só faz sentido testar se o número é divisível por 4 se ele for par (números ímpares não são múltiplos de 4)
- com exceção do 2, todos os outros números primos são ímpares
- para imprimir os múltiplos de 5, não precisa decrementar o `for` de 1 em 1, basta fazê-lo de 5 em 5

Então uma alternativa seria:

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(n + " é par");
        if (n == 2) // 2 é o único número par que é primo
            System.out.print(" e primo");
        else if (n % 4 == 0) // só faz sentido ver se é múltiplo de 4 se for par
            System.out.print(" e múltiplo de 4");
    } else { // se for ímpar, verifica se é primo
        System.out.print(n + " é ímpar");
        boolean primo = true;
        if (n > 2) { // só tem esse if porque o número 1 não é primo
            for (int i = 3; i < n / 2; i += 2) { // não precisa iterar até n, e só itero pelos ímpares
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    primo = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (primo)
                System.out.print(" e primo");
        }
    }
    if (n % 3 == 0)
        System.out.print(" e múltiplo de 3");
    if (n % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print(" e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que " + n + ":");
        // imprimir múltiplos de 5 menores que n em ordem descrescente
        for (int mult = n - 5; mult >= 0; mult -= 5)
            System.out.print(" " + mult);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Usei um algoritmo "ingênuo" para verificar se o número é primo. Claro, se você pesquisar, vai encontrar [muitos outros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/453793), bem mais eficientes, mas para um exercício já está bom.

A saída é:

```
1 é ímpar
2 é par e primo
3 é ímpar e primo e múltiplo de 3
4 é par e múltiplo de 4
5 é ímpar e primo e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 5: 0
6 é par e múltiplo de 3
7 é ímpar e primo
8 é par e múltiplo de 4
9 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
10 é par e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 10: 5 0
11 é ímpar e primo
12 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
13 é ímpar e primo
14 é par
15 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 15: 10 5 0
16 é par e múltiplo de 4
17 é ímpar e primo
18 é par e múltiplo de 3
19 é ímpar e primo
20 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 20: 15 10 5 0
21 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
22 é par
23 é ímpar e primo
24 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
25 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 25: 20 15 10 5 0
26 é par
27 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
28 é par e múltiplo de 4
29 é ímpar e primo
30 é par e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 30: 25 20 15 10 5 0
31 é ímpar e primo
32 é par e múltiplo de 4
33 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
34 é par
35 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 35: 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
36 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
37 é ímpar e primo
38 é par
39 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
40 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 40: 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
41 é ímpar e primo
42 é par e múltiplo de 3
43 é ímpar e primo
44 é par e múltiplo de 4
45 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 45: 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
46 é par
47 é ímpar e primo
48 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
49 é ímpar
50 é par e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 50: 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
51 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
52 é par e múltiplo de 4
53 é ímpar e primo
54 é par e múltiplo de 3
55 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 55: 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
56 é par e múltiplo de 4
57 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
58 é par
59 é ímpar e primo
60 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 60: 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
61 é ímpar e primo
62 é par
63 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
64 é par e múltiplo de 4
65 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 65: 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
66 é par e múltiplo de 3
67 é ímpar e primo
68 é par e múltiplo de 4
69 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
70 é par e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 70: 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
71 é ímpar e primo
72 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
73 é ímpar e primo
74 é par
75 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 75: 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
76 é par e múltiplo de 4
77 é ímpar
78 é par e múltiplo de 3
79 é ímpar e primo
80 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 80: 75 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
81 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
82 é par
83 é ímpar e primo
84 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
85 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 85: 80 75 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
86 é par
87 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
88 é par e múltiplo de 4
89 é ímpar e primo
90 é par e múltiplo de 3 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 90: 85 80 75 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
91 é ímpar
92 é par e múltiplo de 4
93 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
94 é par
95 é ímpar e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 95: 90 85 80 75 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
96 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 3
97 é ímpar e primo
98 é par
99 é ímpar e múltiplo de 3
100 é par e múltiplo de 4 e múltiplo de 5. Múltiplos menores que 100: 95 90 85 80 75 70 65 60 55 50 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TesteCodigo {

private static boolean sePrimo(int numero) {
    for (int j = 2; j < numero; j++) {
        if (numero % j == 0)
            return false;   
    }
    return true;
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> listaInversa = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é par");
        }else {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é impar");
        }
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é multiplo 2");
        }
        if(i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é multiplo 3");
        }
        if(i % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é multiplo 4");
        }           
        if(i % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é multiplo 5");
            lista.add(i);
            if(i == 100) { // somente no final, exibe multiplos invertidos
                int tamanho = lista.size();
                for (int l = 0; l < lista.size(); l++) {
                    listaInversa.add(lista.get(tamanho-1));
                    tamanho--;
                }       
                System.out.println("multiplos de 5 invertidos: " + listaInversa.toString());
                for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Verificação dos numeros primos: ");
    for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        if(sePrimo(i))
            System.out.println("O numero " + i + " é primo");
    }    
}
```

}